# anybody tried and got Dark Souls working on wine?

Tags: 13.04, wine, games

I bought Dark souls on sale from steam and I looked on Wine's website to confirm it is playable. I'm only confused with what I need to install to make the game work. I just would like to know if anyone had any luck with playing the game on Linux and what you had to do to get it working. I appreciate any help that I can get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install wine for it

Just type the following commands in terminal to install wine

```
apt-get install wine
```

then right click the setup.exe file or the installation file you will see the option

`Open With Wine Windows Program Loader` and youre done then just follow the insructions.

That's it.

Comment: Is this for a retail disk? I'm using the steam online version and when clicking play button, a windows pops up and says "directx redist package installing" then it crashes.

Comment: Ya thats because you are trying to run a windows application in Linux and to run any windows application in linux you need to install wine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Wine AppDB entries of [Steam](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444) and [Darks Souls](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26553&iTestingId=74060). This should be first place to look for making things run with Wine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [playonlinux](https://www.playonlinux.com/en/download.html),  package used wine and must have better support for some games.

Or [buy steam for linux](http://store.steampowered.com/about/).